# How to allow multiple users to manage linux files

Tags: linux

As a Linux amateur, I've been able to manage my own files just fine... but now that I'm collaborating with 2 other people, it's becoming a problem. I have tried creating their accounts and making their primary group the chgrp I put on the files, but they don't get edit rights unless I chown them as the user itself. And then my game server eventually takes back ownership.

So for a specific example, let's say I want to create a new user, Johnny. And I want him to only access the BetonQuest subfolder shown here ... and he can edit the folders and files anywhere below that folder. Any hints as to the commands used here?

[image]

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: As Peter suggested, and I second, give `git` serious consideration.  It's designed for distributed collaboration.  It resolves the problem of simultaneous update by two persons.  It's all about the merging ...

Comment: This belongs on unix&linux.SE, not on SO.  Flagging for migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminology: A file has an owner and a group (aka group-owner).  It's called the file's group, not it's chgrp.  `chgrp(1)` is a command for changing the group of a file.

---

#### How to set up shared-access to a directory tree

- Have everyone set their `umask` to 002, so newly-created files and directories have `rwxrwxr-w` permissions (only write for other is masked off from the 0777 that well-designed programs use when they create files).
- add all the users to a group for that project
- optional: set everyone's primary group to the shared group
- If that group isn't the primary group for all the users, then make all the directories setgid so newly-created files and directories inside them will inherit the directory's gid rather than the user's primary group.  (Newly-created directories won't be setgid automatically, though, so this is where your idea of making everyone's primary group the shared group has an advantage.)

  IIRC, only the owner of a file can `chgrp` it.  Once this is set up, it should keep working, but you will probably need to sudo or something to get things set initially.

---

#### More fine-grained control:

If you want different sets of users access to different directories, your best bet is ACLs.  I haven't used them, but they let you add a list of allowed users to each file/directory.  This is much more convenient than having a different group for every different combination of users.  e.g.

```
chgrp -R some_subdir  joe_bill_dave    # Use ACLs instead of this mess
chgrp -R other_subdir bill_dave
```

---

#### A more modern way: version control

Having said all that, you *might* want to use a version-control system like `git` to manage changes.  People could make changes, commit them, then push them to the repo on the server.  Set up a special account on the server that can only run git commands, not a login shell, and add people's ssh public keys to it.

VCS is a more modern way to allow multiple people to modify something than old-school Unix multiple users with write access.

Answer (score 1):

The directory listing looks OK.  You may be experiencing one of the obnoxious quirks of Linux groups.  Try looking at [Linux, Why can't I write even though I have group permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054888/linux-why-cant-i-write-even-though-i-have-group-permissions) and [Why can't a group member modify a file in a group he is part of?](https://serverfault.com/questions/159179/why-cant-a-group-member-modify-a-file-in-a-group-he-is-part-of)

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to add them to sudoers such that they can turn into the user on the box that owns those files.

They would login as themselves

Then they would do sudo commands to edit/config/whatever

sudo -u gameGod vi /some/game/file/config.txt